# page not found error after changes in .htaccess for removing file extension

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am very new to .htaccess behaviour
I am trying to remove extension from php file, I added this to .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
Options All -Indexes
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ $1.php
```

it is working fine but when I want to open admin or trying to open any folder, then it shows
www.mysite.com/admin/

```
Not Found

The requested URL /admin.php was not found on this server.
```

and there is not any admin.php page in my website root folder.

Help will appreciate
Thanks

Comment: Why this is happening.....no body knows??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this way and tell me how it is working for you:

```
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: It did the trick man.. :)   Can you explain this code for me for why my code was causing problem with folders??

Comment: @Dinesh You were not checking if the file exists, so you are rewriting the folder names as well.